# Script working with os.path but not with pathlib (SIGTRAP)

Tags: python

I was advised to take advantage of the pathlib module in Python 3.6, as I am designing a script on Linux that'll be used in production on Windows machines.

`pathlib` does seem promising, but while my code with the `os` module works great:

```
class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Dropbox', 'credits_hd_jobs')

    print(DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH)

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()


    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
```

If I change to the pathlib equivalent:

```
from pathlib import Path as p

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = p.joinpath(p.home(), 'Dropbox', 'credits_hd_jobs/')
    print(DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH)

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()


    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
```

80% I'll get this error in Pycharm:

> Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)

or the script will run, but my triggers won't fire at all.  Confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found the solution:

```
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Dropbox', 'credits_hd_jobs')
```

returns an `str`, while:

```
p.joinpath(p.home(), 'Dropbox', 'credits_hd_jobs/')
```

returns a `PosixPath`

I ended up casting the latter as a string by using `str()`, although this looks ugly to me. I'm keeping the question open for better answers.

Comment: From the `pathlib` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators), it sounds like this is how to do it (or modify the `Observer.schedule()` method to handle both strings and `Path` instances (or just unconditionally apply `str()` to the argument at the start of the function's code).